# Should association bonus be given to suspended users?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension, association-bonus

I just stumbled over [this account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/224710/rajeevk?tab=summary) here on Meta. He joined today and have less than 200 reputation in all other accounts:

> [image]

So I checked the [account with 1 rep](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/8004/rajeevk) to find he is suspended for a week.

Obviously, he has more than 200 there so the association was given based on the "real" reputation.

In my opinion the association bonus should be granted in such cases only after the suspension is over and reputation is recalculated. What do you think?

Comment: I dont think thats needed. Either the user will learn from the initial suspension, or in the worst case, get suspended on the new site as well. Both ways, things work the way they are supposed to. Also, your post is missing some basic things : Why are you suggesting this? How would this help? Is there a problem in the current system?

Comment: In opinion awarding such bonus encourage user to do vote fraud on other site as well. However as system or mod has already detected him but then also in future it can be possible for mods to work extra for such cases when such user starts perform vote fraud on other site as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see a major problem with granting it based on the calculated reputation of a suspended account. The only real *privilege* given was here on meta, not on the site for which the user should have no privileges while the account is suspended.

As suspensions are local to the site on which they're imposed and not considered at all on any other site where the user is participating, I'd say it's pretty consistent the way it is. Additionally, all the association bonus really does is unlock the basic set of creature comforts that an experienced user would want when participating on another site.

If edge cases of this somehow being abused came to light in any appreciable frequency, it's definitely worth revisiting, but my opinion is that it's fine as it is.

Comment: Well said Tim and fair enough, you got me convinced. That specific user is on a roll and joined 10 other sites by now, starting with 101 rep in all of them but like you said, no abuse I can see just out of boredom I guess. :)